# JEE6 JAX RS: Passing State between @GET & @POST methods :: recommended approach

Tags: http, jakarta-ee, jax-rs

I am developing a JEE6 JAX RS Web Application.

The initial HTML5 page of my application is passed a number of query parameters.
This initial HTML5 page is a data entry form.

The URL resembles:-

```
http://host:8080/AAA/bbb/ccc?paramOne=1&paramTwo=XYZ&paramThree=911
```

When the data entry form is submitted I need the @POST method to have access to the query parameters passed on the URL when the HTML5 form was first displayed to the user.

e.g. I need access to paramOne, paramTwo, and paramThree.

Currently i have used

```
@Context
private HttpServletRequest request;
```

...

```
@Path("ccc")
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
public InputStream displayForm(@QueryParam("paramOne") final int param1, @QueryParam("paramTwo") final String param2, @QueryParam("paramThree") final int param3) {

    final HttpSession session = request.getSession();

    session.setAttribute("paramOne", param1);
    session.setAttribute("paramTwo", param2);
    session.setAttribute("paramThree", param3);

    return servletContext.getResourceAsStream("/myform.html");
}
```

...

```
@POST
@Path("/process/form")
public String processForm(final MultivaluedMap<String, String> formData) {

    final HttpSession session = request.getSession();

    System.out.println("POSTED >" + session.getAttribute("paramOne"));
    System.out.println("POSTED >" + session.getAttribute("paramTwo"));
    System.out.println("POSTED >" + session.getAttribute("paramThree"));

    return "TESTING";

}
```

is this approach safe to use?

I am concerned under heavy load (or any load!) sessions get "mixed up" or "miss handled" with un related GETs and POSTs getting/setting the "wrong" query parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sessions do NOT get mixed normally. Mixing sessions would require a serious error from the server implementation (unlikely) or your code (unlikely again if you stick to the server implementation of sessions). And they are not lost as long as the client sends back the session cookie, the server does not restart (or the server is somehow configured to persist sessions) and the session does not timeout.

However, the asynchronous nature of the requests could theoretically lead to a situation where:

1. Client A GETs page with parameters X

   - Session A contains X
2. Client A POSTs from page with parameters X
3. Client A GETs page with parameters Y - *before the server has time to process the request from step 2*

   - Session A contains Y
4. The server starts processing the request from step 2; it will use the Y parameters which is *wrong*.

This scenario may or may not be feasible in your system, but is an example of things could mess up.

Since you are using JAX-RS, I can assume the client is fairly capable. My suggestion is (if possible) to let the *client* manage the state of the application and let the server statelessly serve. This means that the state from the GET request (i.e. `paramOne=1&paramTwo=XYZ&paramThree=911`) is kept in the client and *resent* with the POST, so that the server has the complete data in the single request.

Comment: Nikos thanks for looking at my question: How do i get the client to keep the state?

Comment: That depends on the technology of the client and the frameworks used. If it is JS, there are simple ways to get hold of the request parameters, store them in JS vars and send them back with the POST (as headers, request params, part of the request body etc).

Comment: i was trying to keep this as simple as possible, e.g. just HTML5, maybe some JS if i have to

Comment: Even plain HTML: the GET gets you a form with an action for the POST. Have the server add the request parameters from the GET to the action of the form for the POST.In `processForm()` retrieve the original parameters as request parameters.

Comment: sorry to be dense :( Could you give some pointers on how i "Have the server add the request parameters from the GET to the action of the form for the POST"? Thanks

Comment: What I mean is, eg for JSP in a very crude way, something like: `<form action="<%= request.getContextPath() %>/process/form?paramOne=<%= request.getParameter("paramOne") %>&paramTwo=...">`